# How to create a unique set from CSV in Python and check for values

Tags: python

I have a CSV like this:

```
age,job,marital,y
20, student,single,yes
32,management,single,yes 
49,technician,married,yes 
21,student,single,yes 
34,technician,married,yes
```

I need to build a set of unique jobs.

Read the input from the command line –profession.

Then check if job is in the job list.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your csv for you:

```
age,job,marital,y
20,student,single,yes
32,management,single,yes 
49,technician,married,yes 
21,student,single,yes 
34,technician,married,yes
```

Here is a way to extract unique jobs from a csv file:

```py
# Read csv
with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Turn each line into a list of csv cell values
rows = [line.split(',') for line in lines]

# Find index of `job`
header = rows[0]
job_index = None
for i, value in enumerate(header):
    if value == 'job':
        job_index = i
        break

# Read all `job` values
job_values = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    job_values.append(row[job_index])

# Set of unique jobs
unique_jobs = set(job_values)

# Print
print(unique_jobs)
```

To read from all the lines in the input specified as file names given in command-line arguments, or the standard input if no arguments are provided you could use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) like so:

```py
import fileinput

# Read csv
lines = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    lines.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: How do I get the list of all values of age corresponding to a profession. For e.g. if my command line input is student - I should get the age list such as 20 and 21.

Comment: @SamratSen, this is not in you first question, please edit it if necessary to include all your requirements.